# Friend class not working C++ , declaration of 'class T' shadows template parameter

Tags: c++, scope

I am working on a class to produce a templated Median Heap. I have two classes: a Median Heap (which holds a maxHeap and a minHeap object) , and a Heap object.
I am trying to make the MedianHeap class a friend of the Heap class because I need to access the data members "maxHeap" and "minHeap" from the Heap class. 
These are the main errors I am getting and I've spent hours trying to figure out why:

```
MedianHeap.h:61: error: declaration of ‘class T’
MedianHeap.h:52: error:  shadows template parm ‘class T’
MedianHeap.h:62: error: ‘MedianHeap’ is not a template
MedianHeap.h:115: error: declaration of ‘class T’
MedianHeap.h:150: error: ‘minHeap’ was not declared in this scope
MedianHeap.h:151: error: ‘maxHeap’ was not declared in this scope


template <typename T>
class Heap
{

 public: // after adding in MedianHeap<T>:: scope operator, changing
  // Heap class contents from private: to public: got rid of all of
  // the 'is private' errors that occurred when I did g++ MedianHeap.h 1.cpp
  // and finally,
  // got rid of all the
  template <typename T>
  friend class MedianHeap<T>;


  Heap(int cap);
  int numItems();
  void add(T newItem);
  void fixMinHeap();
  void fixMaxHeap();
  int parent(int index);
  int rightChild(int index);
  int leftChild(int index);
  void minHeapify(int root);
  void maxHeapify(int root);
  T removeMin();
  T removeMax();
  void swap(int a, int b);
  bool searchAndRemove(T& givenItem, bool (*equalTo) (const T&, const T&));
  T locate(int pos);
  int num;
  int capacity;
  bool (*compare) (const T&, const T&);
  T heap[]; //////////// needed, right ? ////////////////
};


template <typename T>
class MedianHeap {

 public:
  //friend class Heap<T>;
  MedianHeap( bool (*lt) (const T&, const T&), bool (*gt) (const T&, const T&), int cap=100 );
  void insert(const T& item);
  T getMin();
  T getMax();
  T getMedian();
  int size();
  int capacity();
  bool deleteItem(T& givenItem, bool (*equalTo) (const T&, const T&));
  void dump();
  int maxHeapSize();
  int minHeapSize();
  T locateInMaxHeap(int pos);
  T locateInMinHeap(int pos);
 private:
  void fixImbalance();
  bool isEmpty();
 void searchForNewMax();
  void searchForNewMin();
  void searchForNewMedian();
  // stores all the numbers less than the current median in a maxHeap.i.e median is the maximum, at the root                                                        \

  template <typename T>
  Heap<T> minHeap;
  //stores all the numbers greater than the current median in a minheap, i.e median is the minimum, at the root                                                     \

  template <typename T>
  Heap<T> maxHeap;
  // tracks total number of items in the whole data structure
  T max;
  T min;
  T median;
  int total;
  int cap;
};
```

So I added the forward declaration and removed the template  syntax above minHeap and maxHeap, but the code still produces a bunch of 'is private' errors. Here are some of the errors coming up and one of the functions where that error appears in:

```
MedianHeap.h: In member function ‘void Heap<T>::fixMinHeap()’:
MedianHeap.h:526: error: ‘minHeap’ was not declared in this scope

/////////////////////
//                 //
//   FIX MIN HEAP  //
//                 //
/////////////////////
template <typename T>
void Heap<T>::fixMinHeap(){
  // get this entry to the right place
  // start at where the item was added, go all the way up to the root if need be
  int i = num;
  while (i != 0 && minHeap.compare(heap[i],heap[parent(i)])){
      swap(i, parent(i));
      i = parent(i); // O(logn)
    }
    //// comparator needs to be used here //////^^^^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a forward declaration of `MedianHeap` before the definition of `Heap` begins, then add a friend declaration referring to the instantiation with `T` inside of `Heap`:

```
template <typename T>
class MedianHeap;

template <typename T>
class Heap
{
    friend class MedianHeap<T>;

public:
    // ...
};
```

As for `minHeap` and `maxHeap`, if I understand correctly, they don't need to be templatised, they can just use instantations of the enclosing `Heap`, because they certainly require the same `T`, don't they?

```
template <typename T>
class MedianHeap {

 // ...
    Heap<T> minHeap;
    Heap<T> maxHeap;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for that.. I added your corrections in but the code still produces 'is private' errors. I included the new errors that print along with one of the functions that produce the errors. Could you please let me know why the friend syntax didn't get rid of these 'is private' errors?